# How to remove unwanted items in `This PC` in Windows Explorer in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1

I want to remove those items as below snapshots i.e. Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos folder.

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Refer to this [guide](http://www.askvg.com/tips-tweak-and-customize-windows-8-1-explorer-this-pc/) which says how to remove it via `regedit`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From [This LifeHacker page](http://lifehacker.com/5535350/hide-pre-populated-items-in-windows-explorers-sidebar):

> To hide it, start up Registry Editor (by hitting Start and searching for "regedit") and navigate to
>
> `HKEY_CLASSES>ROOT\CLSID\{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}\ShellFolder.`
>
> Double click on "Attributes" in the right hand pane and change the value from b084010c to b094010c. Click OK, exit the registry editor, and log out.
>
> The process for the other items is the same, except you use the following keys:
>
> Libraries: change b080010d to b090010d in
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\ShellFolderP
>
> Network: change b0040064 to b0940064 in
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\ShellFolderP
>
> Favorites: change a0900100 to a9400100 in
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}\ShellFolderP
>
> To hide Computer, you'll need to create the Attributes key since none
> exists. Navigate to
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\ShellFolder

Comment: I encountered the error as updated to your answer. DO you have the same issue?

Comment: Please don't update my question to include an error. That's what the comments are for.

Comment: Sorry to do that. Just need to attach the screenshot which we cannot do in a sole comment.

Comment: I encournterd the error as snapshot 1) http://i.stack.imgur.com/RuP6c.png, and 2) http://i.stack.imgur.com/owafg.png Do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

In [this how to geek page](http://www.howtogeek.com/168081/how-to-remove-the-folders-from-my-computer-in-windows-8.1/), they'll show you how to remove the registry folders (didn't let me remove just the key) corresponding to the folders i wanted to remove:

win+r -> type regedit -> navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace

under NameSpace, the delete the corresponding registry folder to the folder you'd like to remove from "this pc":

Desktop Folder – {B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}

Documents Folder – {A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}

Downloads Folder – {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}

Music Folder – {1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}

Pictures Folder – {3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}

Videos Folder – {A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}

note: they also have a windows 10 solution that isn't this one.