# Permanently remove Folder from This PC

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1

I've already [removed the `Folders` from `This PC`](https://superuser.com/q/655804/161601) a couple of times. But I guess after some Windows Updates, these folder return!

**Is there a solution that these folders remain removed or hidden (under This PC and also in the left hierarchical menu)?**

[image]

Comment: Its to be expected that major updates like 8.1, 8.1 Update 1, 8.x Update X will regenerate these registry keys.  You could in theory change the permissions on the registry key, but its much easier to just delete the keys, after major updates.

Comment: I also noticed when having LUA completely turned off in registry, the folders returns on each and every restart... Don't have a problem with windows 8.1, that would be the only one. BTW Windows 10 looks super amazing!

Comment: Do [these other, CLSID registry changes][1] also disappear after updates? It's worth a try.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/765060/how-to-remove-unwanted-items-in-this-pc-in-windows-explorer-in-windows-8-1#answer-765061

Comment: I've spent another hour searching for this. No solution anywhere.

Comment: Microsoft itself give a arrogant answer as "this is an integral part of windows" as if not wanting them THERE is the same as not wanting them at ALL. Typically M$.  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/permanently-remove-folders-desktop-documents/f0124643-931a-4456-9408-c2d4d5803efb?auth=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Tool [OldNewExplorer](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-make-your-81-explorer-work-like-win78-one/), which manipulates shell settings to make Windows Explorer look like Windows 7.

It also makes it so patches can't restore the new look again.

[image: screenshot of explorer after tool used]